# Detect when an element is dragged onto a "delete" icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with a "delete" icon (a small trash bin) and a number of image elements using the jQuery UI sortable plugin. I'd like to be able to drag an element over the trash bin icon and delete it. Is it possible to detect if the element is overlapping the icon, or set a flag if the cursor is over the trash bin with an element attached?

Or maybe this might be possible *without* sortable?

The trash bin is static--it does not move and is not part of the sortable container.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: The page]

Answer (score 0):

You can track the dragged element like this:
Html mark up may look like this:

```
<div id="draggable"><p> drag me</p></div>
<div id="draggable2"><p>drag me too</p></div>
<div id="droppable"><p>Drop inside me</p></div>
```

js would be some thing like this.

```
     $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({tolerance:"touch"});
 $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({tolerance:"touch"});
            $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
              drop: function( event, ui ) {
           var id=   $(this).attr('id');
            var dragged=$(ui.draggable).attr("id");
               alert(dragged);
              }
            });
          });
```

for DEMO:http:http:http://jsfiddle.net/N9dc9/3/